# Spring Security authorization remotely

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently working on Spring Security 4 and everything works fine using default configuration. However, as I hold Spring web application on one machine (192.168.0.1) and HTML Server on another (192.168.0.2), how can I configure the Spring Security to authorization using login form on 192.168.0.2.

Spring Security configuration:

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" >
  default-target-url="http://192.168.0.2/home.html"
</http>
```

Currently, in the login form on 192.168.0.2, I use

```
<form method="post" action="http://192.168.0.1:8080/xxx/login">
    <input type="text" required name="username"/>
    <input type="password" required name="password"/>
    <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

On 192.168.0.2, the user can pass the authorization. However, I cannot find any JSESSIONID in the cookie on 192.168.0.2 or any relevant thing.

My question is, what king of information should I included in the followup ajax request in order to let the Spring Security know who I am?

BTW, if my authorization fails, browser will be redirected to `192.168.0.1/xxx/login`, how can I stay in my custom login page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things simpler lets say you have two machines named.

```
AppIp    : 192.168.0.1
StaticIp : 192.168.0.2
```

Now when you load the form in browser it hits `StaticIp`. Which in turn submits to `AppIp`.

Here's what's happening. When you submit the form to `AppIp`, it returns the `JSESSIONID` or any other `Cookie` to be set for `AppIp`. So the browser does the same, it sets the cookie for `AppIp` not `StaticIp`.

One domain (like google.com) can read/write only it's own cookies. Browser won't set a cookie sent by google for facebook.

That's why you can't see the cookies in `StaticIp` resources, if you load the `AppIp` you would be able to see cookies in it's resources.

Solution is to have a proxy server in front of both the servers. For example Apache HTTPd or NGINX.

Now suppose that proxy server is `ProxyIp` and the configuration is done as following.

```
ProxyIp/static maps to http://192.168.0.2/ (or http://AppIp/)
ProxyIp/app maps to http://192.168.0.1/ (or http://StaticIp/)
```

So now the form URL becomes `http://ProxyIp/static/home.html`

And `/login` URL would become `http://ProxyIp/app/xxx/login`

Now for the browser there's only one domain `ProxyIp` and it would be able to set the cookies for both the mapped servers.

**Note:** You can't send normal Ajax cross domain requests. Browser will block all such attempts. Ajax requests can only be sent to domain which loaded the HTML where the script for Ajax was executed. It can be done with some configuration for CORS, but that's too much pain and sweat.